# How to apply common CSS classes to shadow elements?

Tags: html, css, web-component, shadow-dom, constructable-stylesheet

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625017/override-styles-in-a-shadow-root-element/47633167):

> Because of the isolation of styles, which is a feature of Shadow DOM, you cannot define a global CSS rule that will be applied in the Shadow DOM scope.

Is there any way to define simple CSS classes globally in some global `styles.css` file (for example) that we can use in all kinds of places and re-use them in individual components?

Currently, the simple answer would be to add a corresponding `<link href="styles.css">` tag to every single component that we define. This has been [proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57022282/alternatives-to-bootstrap-js-does-not-work-inside-shadow-dom) to allow web components use bootstrap classes, and again [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54907742/how-to-apply-custom-css-to-shadow-dom-inside-elements) to support ionic. Is that a good approach? Would that not be terrible performance-wise, if we included big `styles.css` in tens or hundreds of components?

Answer (score 2):

[Constructable Stylesheets](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/constructable-stylesheets) are a proposal to solve exactly that problem.

In a nutshell, it's a way to share the same stylesheet across components without requesting the stylesheet each time. Currently it's Chrome only, but there is a [polyfill](https://github.com/calebdwilliams/construct-style-sheets), and, Firefox at least, seem to [support this proposal](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5394843094220800).

Comment: Sweet! I will try it out the next few days!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could help you. From this link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM

You have the following:

> **Internal versus external styles**
>
> In the above example we apply style to the Shadow DOM using a 
> element, but it is perfectly possible to do it by referencing an
> external stylesheet from a  element instead.
>
> For example, take a look at this code from our
> popup-info-box-external-stylesheet example (see the source code):
>
> ```
> // Apply external styles to the shadow dom
> const linkElem = document.createElement('link');
> linkElem.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
> linkElem.setAttribute('href', 'style.css');
>
> // Attach the created element to the shadow dom
> shadow.appendChild(linkElem);
> ```
>
> Note that  elements do not block paint of the shadow root, so
> there may be a flash of unstyled content (FOUC) while the stylesheet
> loads.
>
> Many modern browsers implement an optimization for  tags either
> cloned from a common node or that have identical text, to allow them
> to share a single backing stylesheet. With this optimization the
> performance of external and internal styles should be similar.

To make it as independent and modular as possible, I would propose something like that:

```
let myStyles = querySelector('rel[href="style.css"]');
shadowDOM.appendChild(myStyles);
```

Normally, you don't have another option except of adding the styles directly to the shadow DOM.